# VBA code works in new workbook, but not the one I want it to work in

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook and the macro doesn't work, basically just copying from cell A3 and down with values in each worksheet, then pasting each of that into a new summary worksheet in succession.

When I literally create a new workbook and copy and paste all my sheets into the new workbook everything works fine. But If I stay in the old work book it gives the error

> Select Method of Worksheet class failed

It didn't fail in the other 2 workbooks I created with the exact same sheets that I copied over...why this one particular workbook?

I close all other workbooks to avoid error with ActiveWorkBook - perhaps not the best way of doing things, but it shouldn't be affecting this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectItemsEstimate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Business Unit Key" _
            And ws.Name <> "dv" And ws.Name <> "cc" And ws.Name <> "wer" And ws.Name <> "dafd" _
            And ws.Name <> "Master Sheet Summary Data" _
            And ws.Name <> "Query for Macro" _
            And ws.Name <> "Query for Macro 2 with Format" _
            And ws.Name <> "Paste all values" _
            And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then

            Worksheets(ws.Name).Select
            Range("A3", Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"
                ' paste
                .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) No need to select - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and 2) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row: `Range("A3", Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select` is problematic.

Comment: Check to see if ActiveWorkbook is null before you continue your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Select Method of Worksheet class failed

This may be caused by worksheet visibility - excel cannot select hidden or very hidden worksheet. Try this code to check whether some sheets are not visible

```
Sub CheckSheetVisibility()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next
End Sub
```

And here how you can refactor your code to avoid issues with ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet statements, and without using .Select/.Activate methods:

```
Sub SelectItemsEstimate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsToCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsToCopyTo = wb.Sheets("Summary")

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Business Unit Key" _
            And ws.Name <> "dv" And ws.Name <> "cc" And ws.Name <> "wer" And ws.Name <> "dafd" _
            And ws.Name <> "Master Sheet Summary Data" _
            And ws.Name <> "Query for Macro" _
            And ws.Name <> "Query for Macro 2 with Format" _
            And ws.Name <> "Paste all values" _
            And ws.Name <> "Summary" Then

            With ws
                Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy
            End With

            wsToCopyTo.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Vitaliy. there are hidden sheets, this is probably causing some issues. Thanks for the tip on avoiding Activate/select.